# Browser opens twice when running script

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm working on a web driver and I'm trying to implement classes into my code. I had this working but as soon as I turned it into a class my browser started opening twice when I ran the program. It will open a browser, then open the second browser, run the commands and then leave the first browser open. Can any tell me why this is happening? This is just an example of how is is formatted.

```
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class About(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def pause(self):
        time.sleep(1)

    def run(self):
        self.driver.get('https://google.com')
        self.pause()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

go = About(webdriver.Chrome())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    go.run()
    go.tearDown()
```

Comment: it's works correctly for me , the only change that I made was add `chromedriver.exe` path as argument to `webride.Chrome('here')`, Are you using chrome driver?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following that. I get a `'chromedriver' is not defined` error

Comment: You should download chromedriver.exe then add it's path as argument to webderiver.Chrome() function , did you do that?

Comment: If I run your code exactly as written, I only get a single browser.